# How to split MS Access form into multiple pages?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am new to MS Access and I'd like to split a lengthy form into multiple pages. It'd be better if I can use 'next' and 'previous' buttons to navigate within the same form through multiple pages.

I'm using MS Office 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `page break` control from the `Design` tab on the Ms Access Ribbon.

[image: page break icon]

You drag the page break on to the form and it shows as a couple of dots on the left of the form.

Then use the form's `GoToPage` method to navigate between pages.

Comment: How can I use my next page please ? Don't know how to use GoToPage method :/ Thanks